# Convert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() time from UTC to ET

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am updating my dataframe field *Create Date* using **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()** time function of Spark SQL. The value being returned are in the UTC timezone.

I want the values in Eastern Time (with daylight savings handled). I would like to do the conversion of timezone when I am passing my SQL query to *sqlContext.sql*. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use from_utc_timestamp fucntion to do this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType

// This sample syntax. You can replace your value at literal location.
from_utc_timestamp(lit("2018-12-01 00:00:00").cast(TimestampType), "EST5EDT")
```

This must handle Daylight savings too.